# meaning of int near* far* huge* i;

Tags: c, pointers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [difference between far pointer and near pointer in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1749904/difference-between-far-pointer-and-near-pointer-in-c)
>   [What is near, far and huge pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3575592/what-is-near-far-and-huge-pointers)
>   [Near and Far pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3869830/near-and-far-pointers)

I am not very much clear with these pointers.
plz explain me the meaning of following types of declaration

```
int near* far* huge* i;
int far* huge* huge i;
```

etc etc

Comment: It means the code you're looking at is almost certainly horribly out of date, to the point that you'll probably have to do a lot of work to get it to work with a reasonably modern compiler (in fact, a total rewrite from the ground up may well be easier than trying to figure out what the code does, or how).