# What's the real size of `size_t`, `uintptr_t`, `intptr_t` and `ptrdiff_t` type on 16-bit systems using segmented addressing mode?

Tags: c++, c, windows

Well, `size_t`, `uintptr_t`, `intptr_t` and `ptrdiff_t` type defined in C programming language really puzzles me.

I noticed that on **32-bit** systems using **flat memory mode**, the real size of above four types is:

```
sizeof(size_t) = sizeof(uintptr_t) = sizeof(intptr_t) = sizeof(ptrdiff_t) = 4
```

And on **64-bit** systems using **flat memory mode**, the real size of above four types is:

```
sizeof(size_t) = sizeof(uintptr_t) = sizeof(intptr_t) = sizeof(ptrdiff_t) = 8
```

But, I'm still curious about the real size of these four types on **16-bit** systems using **segmented addressing mode**.

According to [Windows 3.1x](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_3.1x), Windows 3.1x is a series of 16-bit operating systems. But I can't find a suitable C language compiler to test and validate the real answer.

Comment: You should not have taken that job in the operating system museum ;)

Comment: "But I can't find a suitable C language compiler to test and validate the real answer." - I think you'll find that windows 3.1 pre-dates these standard pseudo-types.

Comment: Back in the windows 3.1 and dos 3.x...6.x days, the memory models of x86..286 were modeled explicitely. The compilers were aware of it. Both Borland C++ (2.x...3.x) and MSVC had similar memory model classes you would either pick generically to compile your program (compile with large, small, huge,...) memory model. Or you could indulge in #pragma orgies to do fine grained control.

Comment: In a label far, far away....

Answer (score 1):

In [real mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_mode), `size_t` and `ptrdiff_t` are 16 bit types. The size of a pointer depends on whether it's a [near, far, or huge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Memory_Model#Pointer_sizes) pointer. Near pointers have 16 bits, the other 32 bits. `intptr_t` and `uintptr_t` were only defined much later in C99.

Comment: I think, at that time, there was not even ``<stdint.h>``.

Comment: @BitTickler if we go back far enough, there was no real mode either. That is, it wasn't called real mode. Of course whatever the 8086 processor was doing was "real"; that needed no mention. :)

Comment: @nwellnhof Are you sure that `size_t` and `ptrdiff_t` weren't dependent on the *memory model* selected for the program? I used this stuff, but I don't remember very well.

Comment: @Kaz I'm not 100% sure, but I think they were 16 bit even in the huge model. AFAIK, the huge model didn't allow 32 bit array indices or arrays with more than 64K elements. You could allocate arrays with a total size larger than 64 KB, though.

Answer (score 1):

That, at least potentially, depends on which compiler you are using.

As a data point from the 16-bit era, the Borland Turbo C++ 3.0 manual has this to say:

> The integer type of the result of **sizeof** is **size_t**, defined as **unsigned int** in stddef.h.

(emphasis in original.)

The size of `unsigned int` was 16 bits, independent of the memory model.

(None of the other types you asked about existed yet, or, if they did, were not supported by this particular compiler.)

Comment: Turbo C++ had 5 different memory models, the sizes of these things varied among them

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3575592/what-are-near-far-and-huge-pointers <- The answers there state differently. And I think, they are right. far and huge were composite values. Far was segment:offset and Huge was normalized. 32Bit in total.

Comment: @M.M: the size of pointers varied depending on the memory model.  The size of `size_t` did not, at least not according to the manual.

Comment: @BitTickler: none of the answers to that question even *mention* `size_t` !