# Can not get Visual Studio C++ to compile old code using huge pointers, how do I convert?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm trying to refurbish some old code with lines like:

```
BYTE huge *    _lpDIBHdr;            // Pointer to BITMAPINFOHEADER
```

in it. How best to do that? Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

This evidently was written to be 16-bit real-mode x86 code, where `huge` was needed in order to have arrays larger than 64KB.  See [What are near, far and huge pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3575592/what-are-near-far-and-huge-pointers), and [What conventions and language extensions did people use to program the 8086 and 80286?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/2366/what-conventions-and-language-extensions-did-people-use-to-program-the-8086-and/2374#2374) on Retrocomputing.SE.

If you are lucky, that's the only part of the code that's specific to x86-16, and it is otherwise portable standard C.  In which case you can simply delete all instances of the `huge` keyword, or insert `#define huge /* nothing */` at the top of every source file.  In a 32- or 64-bit compiler there is no such 64KB limit.  You can treat `near` and `far` similarly.

If you are unlucky, then the code may contain lots of other instances non-portable x86-16-specific code, and then you have a long porting project ahead of you.  This may include instances like `huge` that are overt (program won't compile), or more subtle (program compiles but doesn't run correctly, or contains hard-to-find bugs).